# insert data into forests in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

we know that ML is spreading data on multiple hosts trough forests and choose a policy on documents to equqlize the number off documents on every node. But, on multiple inserts, how can we tell marklogic to choose forests from different nodes to insert data on it in order not to saturate certain node?

Comment: Normally, you wouldn't. Are you seeing that a particular node is "running hot" or somehow a bottleneck, or anticipating that it might become an issue? Are you referring to inserts for the same URI or different URIs?

Answer (score 0):

MarkLogic server makes sure that the data is equally distributed across forests and nodes. That process is called rebalancing and, in 99.99% of the cases, let the server do what it thinks is best. You can read more about rebalancing [here](https://www.marklogic.com/blog/database-rebalancing/).

In which situation are you seeing "saturation" of a certain node?